# Select distinct in dictionary value as object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

mainDictionary has all records so I am trying to get distinct records here on ColorPriceDictionary but I am having duplicate records

```
objProductFrontModel.ColorPriceDictionary =
                    mainDictionary.Select(m => new { m.Value.ColorId, m.Value.ColorText, m.Value.SizeId })
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToDictionary(m => m.ColorId, m => new ProductDetail { ItemText = m.ColorText, ItemId = m.SizeId });
```

Comment: could you show some actual example of output ?

Comment: @Noctis Its giving me key repetation error

Comment: I'll assume there's some other key, since if the color id's a are unique, the `.Distincit` seems redundant to begin with ... ?

Comment: since key here is ColorID does other affect its key??

Comment: you are having duplicate records on basis of what? Id?

Answer (score 0):

`Distinct` uses the `equals` method, `IEquatable` or `IComparable` on the class to determine distinctness.

When you say `new { m.Value.ColorId, m.Value.ColorText, m.Value.SizeId }`, you are creating an anonymous (unnamed) class with three unnamed member variables. The default `equals` implementation provided by the C# compiler for anonymous classes is to compare *all three* member variables. So after your `Distinct`, every result instance has a unique combination of the three variables, but not necessarily just `colorId`.

Two solutions:

1) mplement a custom `IComparator<T>` which compares just the `colorId` of the element OR

2) Implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on a defined `Element` class and then use that in the `Select` clause.

```
class MySelectorElement
{
    string ColorId { get; set; }
    string ColorText { get; set; }
    string SizeId { get; set; }

    override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is MySelectorElement)
        {
            return object.Equals(this.ColorId, ((MySelectorElement)other).ColorId);
        }
        else return false;
    }

    override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ColorId.getHashCode();
    }
}

//...

... Select(new MySelectorElement { ColorId = m.Value.ColorId, ... })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

All key values in a dictionary must be distinct, but you aren't selecting distinct key values. You're selecting distinct tuples of colorID, ColorText, and SizeID. Within these distinct tuples, there are obvously some duplicate values for ColorID, which is why you're getting an error.

I suspect that if you remove SizeID from your selection, this will succeed, since ColorText seems obviously dependent on SizeID. Your other choice is to select these tuples into a data structure that tolerates duplicate values of ColorID, like a list. If that won't work, I'd say you need to take a step back and think about a different approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: so what may be the possible solution?

Comment: @brykneval the possible solution depends on how you want to handle the fact that you have more than one SizeId value for at least one ColorId value.